# Optical character recognition for LibreOffice

Tags: ocr

I have a paper document. There are more pages containing a table with 3 columns (current number, name and a grade).

I scanned it and got 16 jpeg documents. Each jpeg is a scanned page.

Now, I need an OCR to convert each jpeg into text, in order to insert this table in an excel document.

I use LibreOffice and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: No personal experience but take a look at the [OCR - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR)

Answer (score 4):

The [**Scanning and OCR**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/department/precise/scanning-ocr/) page on Ubuntu Apps show us several alternatives, of which I suggest you to use [**XSane Image Scanning Program**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/xsane/) or [**Simple Scan**](https://launchpad.net/simple-scan) (usually pre-installed in 12.04 and maybe earlier versions too) and/or [**gscan2pdf**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gscan2pdf/), to get your documents scanned.

My favorite is **gscan2pdf**, which allow you to follow the Scan/OCR process in the same GUI with no problem.

[image]

*Please notice that I am attempting to run a OCR to a screenshot.*

You simply Scan or Import the documents/images and go to the Tools Menu, choose the OCR Option and you'll be asked for a OCR Engine, simply choose the one that gives the best results for you and click "Start OCR".

[image]

You'll find the OCR Output in the tab with the same title as shown in the next screenshot.

[image]

Please note that even with good quality images the OCR may fail interpreting certain characters, which may result in misspelled words or simply Egyptian hieroglyphics. The process to OCR a large set of documents may delay for a while.

Here is a link to a comprehensive video which explains the process to Scan and OCR in GScan2PDF: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjjogfWfWsQ

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Bit late in answering this question.

But for others who come to this page searching for an OCR solution for LibreOffice,  I recently develeped LibreOCR, an OCR plugin for LibreOffice.

It is part of [Indic-OCR](http://indic-ocr.github.io) project.

The extension can now be found from [LibreOffice Extensions Website](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/libre-ocr)